# What are the practical steps to migrate a virtual machine from VMWare ESXi to XenServer?

Tags: vmware-esxi, xen, migration, xenserver

I now have a few virtual machines (Windows and Linux) running on VMWare esxi and we are considering migrating to XenServer. Is this possible? What are the practical steps?

Answer (score 3):

XenConvert 2,0 is a Tool from Citrix that does the job

Comment: Yup. Just boot from the XenServer install CD and doing a P2V migration is one of the options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can move VMs around.  The easiest is to use one of the tools that reads VMFS volumes, like vmfs-tools, and copy the contents of each VM to a corresponding filesystem on the Xen server, then configure and boot.